VS Code launch.json set 'runtimeVersion:16', but it still uses v18
I have installed nvm and installed node v18 and v16.
I specified runtimeVersion in the launch.json, here is the config:
{
     "type": "node",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Program",
     "runtimeVersion": "16",
     "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js"
}

but every time I debug the process, it shows it's using v18.
I tried to change the runtimeVersion to 16 but it doesn't work.

It turns out that the node version is specified in the settings.json file. The runtimeVersion works after the debug.javascript.defaultRuntimeExecutable is commented out.

